# List of differences between unassociated models and associated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, if we take a `Post` model that can `belongs_to` a `User`:

1. `Post.create` when not associated = `user.posts.create` when associated.
2. `Post.new` when not associated = `user.posts.build` when associated.
3. `@post = Post.find(params[:id])` when not associated = ??? when associated?

what would I use to fill in the third one with, and where can I go find a list of things you do differently when you're going through associations?

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to do?

Comment: this is just an example. I'm just confused on how to implement typical REST actions when you're dealing with a model that `belongs_to` another model.  For example, in index actions normally I would just do something like `@post = Posts.all`, but if posts `belongs_to` a user then I have to do something like `@user = current_user` then`@posts = @user.posts`.

Comment: `user.posts.find(params[:id])` works exactly as you'd expect it to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The association equivalent of `@post = Post.find(params[:id])`
would be: `user.posts.find(params[:id])`

For more information on what you can do with associations, I can strongly recommend reading the relevant Rails Guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

(and then all the others after that) :)